# Even after removing Libreoffice, software update keeps showing me the Libreoffice updates

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04. I had libreoffice removed as I use online service so desktop app are not needed. However, even after removing the software update keeps telling me to download and update libreoffice packages.

[image]

How do I remove them from the updates also and why it keeps tracking Libreoffice? Is it that some portion of libreoffice is still on my machine somewhere?

**Update**:
I removed using the following command

> sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* && sudo apt-get clean && sudo
> apt-get autoremove

Comment: Please add how you have tried to remove the software previously? 
Have you tried using apt in terminal with --purge?

Comment: Is part of the base Ubuntu OS software. Did you just delete the directories?

Comment: Please check the question, I just updated

Comment: Look at the output of `apt list --upgradable` to see which packages you missed. Using wildcards with apt-get is possible, but can lead to unexpected results...as you have discovered. Opinion: I generally recommend against using wildcards with apt for most users. If you don't know actual names of the packages, then you're perhaps not quite ready to be installing or removing them.

Comment: Also see whether LO is not also installed as snap: see if it is in the output of `snap list`. If  yes, remove with snap command or Ubuntu software.